# use ant1.7.1.jar as external library in ant build -Error

Tags: ant

My ant versions is  ANT1.6 , this is Appserver customized  versionn, which has some AppServer specific customized Tasks defined and it is preventing me from upgrading ANT as it is tightly coupled with AppServer upgrade, We have a requirement where user passes a list of files and I have to check if that files exists in a target location , if they exist then delete them and if they do not exist then throw a build failure error. After some troubleshooting I have decided to use ANT1.7 as an external library , below is my code snippet for validating if the file exists

```
  <target name="validate.file" depends="defineResource,validate.dir">
    <echo message = " The Filelist is : ${file.list} "/>
    <condition property="is.missing">
      <resourcecount when="ne" count="0">
        <difference id="is.missing">
          <intersect>
            <filelist id="required" dir="${target.location}" files="${file.list}"/>
            <fileset id="existing" dir="${target.location}" includes="*.*"/>
          </intersect>
          <filelist refid="required"/>
        </difference>
      </resourcecount>
    </condition>
    <fail if="is.missing" message= " File ${toString:missing} is missing from the list of files provided for removing, please recheck and submit correct "/>
  </target>
```

I am using taskdef to load the ANT1.7.1.jar and Tried the below snippet

1 Approach

```
  <target name = "defineResource">
    <echo message = "Present in Resource Class "/>
    <taskdef name="resourcecount" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ResourceCount">
      <classpath>
         <pathelement location="/jass/deploy-process/deploy-engine/build/lib/apache-ant-1.7.1.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="difference" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Difference">
      <classpath>
          <pathelement location="/jass/deploy-process/deploy-engine/build/lib/apache-ant-1.7.1.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="intersect" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Intersect">
      <classpath>
          <pathelement location="/jass/deploy-process/deploy-engine/build/lib/apache-ant-1.7.1.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>
  </target>
```

2nd Approach

```
  <target name = "defineResource">
    <echo message = "Present in Resource Class "/>
    <taskdef name="resourcecount" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ResourceCount,org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Difference,org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Intersect">
      <classpath>
         <pathelement location="/jass/deploy-process/deploy-engine/build/lib/apache-ant-1.7.1.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>
  </target>
  <target name = "defineDifference">
    <echo message = "Present in Difference Class "/>
    <taskdef name="difference" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Difference">
      <classpath>
          <pathelement location="/jass/deploy-process/deploy-engine/build/lib/apache-ant-1.7.1.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>
  </target>
  <target name = "defineIntersect">
    <echo message = "Present in Intersect Class "/>
    <taskdef name="intersect" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Intersect">
      <classpath>
          <pathelement location="/jass/deploy-process/deploy-engine/build/lib/apache-ant-1.7.1.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>
  </target>
```

But none of my approach to use Taskdef is working , they are throwing build failure error

No public execute() in class org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Difference

No public execute() in class org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Intersect

I am really confused on how to fix this , Please advice me if I am doing the right approach or else if there is any other way that i can achieve my actual requirement to search the files from file list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [include ANT1.7.1 jar in my build.xml for taskdefs.ResourceCount](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528372/include-ant1-7-1-jar-in-my-build-xml-for-taskdefs-resourcecount)

Comment: Rebse- Thank you very much for your update, Can you please let me know if there is any other way to achieve my requirement , I am even ready to use AntContrib , I am desperate need to solve this and I am new to using ANT and struck in this old version and could not move forward

Comment: Why don't you install ant under a different directory and reset ANT_HOME?

Comment: Mark , can you please guide me on how do i reset ANT_HOME inside my existing build.xml while executing this particular target , There are other target definations in the same build.xml which need ANT1.6 ( Customized WebSphere ANT definations) , So if you could please guide me on how to just reset the ANT_HOME while invoking this target defination, I would be able to fix this